# Circular uniform distribution using copula

Tags: probability, self-study, copula

$\Theta$ is a uniform random variable on the interval $[0, 2\pi)$, and we have $X = \cos(\Theta)$ and $Y = \sin(\Theta)$.

Suppose $(x,y)$ is a point inside the unit circle. Then, the arc length that is shown in white in Fig. 3.2.a on page 56 of *An Introduction to Copulas* ([Nelson, 2006](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=B3ONT5rBv0wC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)) is $2\pi H(x,y)$, where $H(x,y)$ is a joint distribution function of RVs $X$ and $Y$.

Could you please help me to understand why the arc length is $2\pi H(x,y)$?

[EDIT] 
[image: Captured from the book]

Comment: By definition, $H(x,y)$ is the chance that a random point $\Theta$ on the unit circle has coordinates $X$ and $Y$ not exceeding either $x$ or $y$, respectively.  The white arc shown in the figure depicts that event.  Because the distribution of $\Theta$ is uniform, the chance is proportional to the arc length.  The normalization factor is the total arc length, equal to $2\pi$.  Because both the question and this explanation will be unintelligible to anyone without access to the book, we have to close the question pending further explanation.

Comment: @whuber thanks! I just put the figure. Yes, I should've seen it if in the form of $l/2\pi = H(x,y)$, where $l$ is the arc length.

Comment: You should also add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: How is $(x,y)$ in your second picture considered as being _inside_ the unit circle?

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate sorry. It is 3.2.a. I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$H$ refers to a *bivariate distribution function.*  In general this means

$$H(x,y) = \Pr(X \le x,\ Y \le y).$$

In the $(x,y)$ plane, such a region is a rectangle bounded at the top by $y$, at the right by $x$, and infinite to the left and down, as shown by the gray regions in both figures.

These particular random variables are confined to the unit circle because $X^2 + Y^2 = \cos^2(\Theta) + \sin^2(\Theta) = 1$.  Moreover, they are uniformly distributed on that circle because $\Theta$ has a uniform distribution on the interval $[0, 2\pi)$.  *Uniform* means the chance that $(X,Y)$ lies along any particular (measurable) part of the circle is directly proportional to the length of that part.  Since the total length is the perimeter $2\pi$, the constant of proportionality must be $1/(2\pi)$.

Consequently, $H(x,y)$ must be proportional to the total length of any parts of the circle lying within the semi-infinite rectangle determined by $(x,y)$.  The figures show two examples, one where $(x,y)$ is in the disk bounded by the circle and another where $(x,y)$ is outside that disk.  In either case, though, $H(x,y)$ must equal $1/(2\pi)$ times this total arc length.  Multiplying this equality yields the statement in the question: $2\pi H(x,y)$ is the total length of arcs to the left of and below the point $(x,y)$.